# When to escape data being sent with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, security

I need to escape text that is being outputted via AJAX. If I submit script to the database, like `<script>alert('hello world');</script>`, then a popup is executed on the page.

This here is my function that is setting the data, and then grabbing data to be sent via AJAX.

```
function add_order() {
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
        $add_order = $this->order_model->set_order($_POST['text']);
        if($add_order==false){
            echo "fail";
            return false;
        }
        $order_data = $this->order_model->get_order_by_id($add_order);
        echo json_encode($order_data);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Jquery Code:

```
$('#create_order').submit(function(){
        $.post('/order/add_order/', $('#create_order').serialize(), function(data){
            var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
            var obj_item = obj[0];
            $('tr.'+obj_item.id).append("<td>" + obj_item.text + "</td>");
            msg('success', 'Part #'+obj_item.number+' has been successfully created');
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

How do I stop obj_item.text from executing scripts?

Comment: use [0].innerHTML instead of .append()

Comment: @dandavis: That won't help.

Comment: @SLaks: why won't it help? innerHTML doesn't execute script tags, whereas html(), append(), load() and friends "helpfully" eval dynamic script tags...

Comment: @dandavis: `<img onerror="alert('XSS!');" src="http://google.com" />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build DOM elements and set text instead of building HTML:

```
$("<td />", { text: obj_item.text }).appendTo('tr.tr.' + obj_item.id);
```

Comment: Instead of restructuring the way I build DOM (even though I know the way you are telling me to do it is the right way - It will just be a lot of work is all), is there a way to parse my current structure to text? like by doing:  $('tr.'+obj_item.id).append("<td>" + obj_item.text.text() + "</td>");

Comment: That's called HTML-escaping.  There are no built-in methods to do it, but you can write one yourself: `return $('<div />', { text: text }).html()`

Comment: Why do you use `$("<td />",` and not `$("<td>",`?

Comment: @qwertynl: IIRC, `$(element string)` must be well-formed.

Comment: @SLaks No it does not. And yours is not well formed at all. You could even do `$("<td></td>",`.

Comment: There are no self closing `td`'s that I know of :-P @SLaks

Comment: @qwertynl: I was right all along.  The docs say: `To ensure cross-platform compatibility, the snippet must be well-formed. Tags that can contain other elements should be paired with a closing tag:`  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#creating-new-elements

Comment: @qwertynl: No.  However, I don't see any browsers that fail on this.

Comment: Can we [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42983/discussion-between-qwertynl-and-slaks)? @SLaks

Answer (score 0):

If the submitted data can only contain plain text, ensure that you use `.text()` to re-insert it back into the DOM - using `.text` will prevent any embedded tags from being rendered as HTML or otherwise handled by the browser.

You should also validate data on the server before it's stored, and for extra measure perform client-side verification before posting the data to the server.  IMHO, it's better to reject bad data than to simply escape it.

Comment: From what I've been reading on these forums, it seems like the consensus is that data should be inserted into the database raw

Comment: @Slaks by sanitize I meant check for conformance, and reject if unacceptable - not silently "clean it up".

Comment: Then it won't help; you'll still need to escape.